# Why does kendo ui datasource sync not work?

Tags: kendo-ui, synchronization

Can anyone tell me why sync does not send any json data to server ?
http://jsbin.com/pudetaso/1/edit

Comment: Look at your datasource that is coming up in your alert box.  Is that what the server is expecting?

Comment: clearly domain.com is not my domain. i am testing if sync works or not.it should not matter whether server is expecting or not, right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have only specified the transport.update method. You are creating a new item which uses transport.create instead of transport.update.

Comment: I just added "create" but it did not help much.